# Naming module same as library

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a folder named 'http' in my project but then the code inside the folder uses another library that uses the http library which can't be resolve because it resolves to my 'http' folder. I tried to have my `__init__.py` do this:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
import http
```

But it doesn't seem to help. I am using Python3.6

Comment: why don't you just rename it?

Comment: but i really want to name it http...

Comment: How about naming it HTTP instead of http? Will that help?

Comment: Aside from confusing the interpreter, you're going to confuse any other person you work with that is aware of the built in library. Just pick another name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's not a good idea to name your module as already existing standard module. Because it makes you unable to import both within a script in your project. PEP8 recommends to append already existing standard names with underscore symbol in order to resolve such collisions. So I would recommend you to rename your module into `http_`.

```
http -> http_
```

[PEP8 - names to avoid](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#names-to-avoid)